# How to hide the products base on the category in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, category, catalog, category-products

I need to hide the products based on the category.

**To Do :**
If i need to hide the products which are assigned on the particular category called Shirts, all products of this category need to hide. How can i find the solution are is there any option in magento to do this.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you means hide on category page ???

Comment: Yes i need to hide the products from category page frontend

Comment: you want to disable category ???

Comment: If the category disabled the product will be show are not?

Comment: where product will be show ???

Comment: In the front-end store i'am having all category page in that all product will be shown and when searching the product the product of this category will be shown

Comment: category disabled are not show on frontend.so product are not show

Comment: When search this product of this category it is showing then how can i manage it